# Python ArgParse shared by several files

Tags: python, oop

I have a main entry-point class (factory) that creates different classes:

```
main.py
class_a.py
class_b.py
```

By triggering this:

```
$ main.py --class a --another_argument foo
```

I want to trigger class_a.py (which holds `ClassA`) with access to the same `argparse`, and without passing it into the constructor. is that even possible? do I have to use `argparse` again inside `ClassA` to read all the incoming arguments?

Comment: It looks a really bad idea! There should be only one entrypoint.However, if you really need, just add a `common.py` (for example) and put argparse on it and share between modules.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you can't use the *exact* same parser, since presumably the `--class` option will dictate which other options are needed. (Or if it doesn't, then `main.py` should be able to parse all the arguments itself, and simply pass the necessary values to `ClassA` or `ClassB` as appropriate when they are instantiated.)

Comment: @felipsmartins there is one entry point, but I want to have a main file to invoke the correct class, for example:
`start.py` with argparse which triggers `cloud1.py` or `cloud2.py` 
And I want to have the ability to use the same argparse on `start.py` and `cloud1.py` or `cloud2.py` (which means - direct usage or via `start.py`)